# SQL Assemblies and SQL Injections

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005, sql-injection

I have a couple of SQL CLR projects that are added into my SQL Server 2005 as assemblies. They are accessed from my web app via stored procedures that fire off the assemblies.

How and what are best practices for preventing SQL injections in my SQL assemblies?

The assemblies have a bunch of code that builds crazy SQL statements (example):

```
        sqlBuff.Append("SELECT ");
        //  Always put replicate weight values on the first.
        sqlBuff.Append(colBuff.ToString());

        sqlBuff.AppendLine(" FROM ");
        String tableNames = colTabNameHelper.GetTableNameList(colNames);
        String joinStr = colTabNameHelper.CreateJoinStr(tableNames);

        sqlBuff.Append(joinStr);
        sqlBuff.AppendLine(" WHERE (");

        sqlBuff.Append(inMatrix.WeightVar);
```

Can I prevent injections here too? Or does .NET/SQL Server help? Should I worry about this?

Comment: Depending on where the strings come from, that looks vulnerable to me. There's no magic in .NET or SQL server that will automatically prevent SQL injection.

Comment: yeah that's what i thought. I can prevent the stored procedures from injecting code there and the assemblies won't have access to user input directly. The worry comes from the fact that if somehow the data in the db gets injectable code, then the query in the assembly could grab it and inadvertently do bad things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitive way of avoiding injection attacks is to use [Parameters](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter).  Are you able to use these in the embedded assemblies?